# How should I parse "有过之而无不及"?

Tags: expressions, phrase-meaning

Chinese-study newbie here! I recently saw the idiom "有过之而无不及," which the online dictionary translates as "to not be inferior in any aspect." I understand this on an idiomatic level, but am struggling to parse how the pieces come together on a literal level. Is it something like

有   过    之   而   无   不及
"cross it  and  not  fall-short"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

有过之 - possibly be superior

而 - and

无不及 - (certainly) not be inferior = (at least) equal

有过之而无不及 = at or above a certain level

Example:

泰森的名氣比阿里的有过之而无不及 - Tyson's fame is comparable to Ali's and possibly greater

Answer (score 1):

means totally better than you.

只能比你好，没有比你差
不管怎么比，都是如此。

Answer (score 1):

It comes from classical Chinese, so the meanings and the grammatical structures are different from contemporary Chinese.
In this phrase,
"有"：be,have
"过"：be superior to
"之": that
“而”：and
"无": nothing
"不及": be inferior to